# Reactjs - Different columns layouts on table row affects other table rows

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm having this issue where if I apply different column layouts to different rows in React, it messes up the column layout of other rows.  For example, `SpecialRows` are rows in a table that I want to display. `SpecialBar` is bar that exists above the table which contains other stuff like filtering, searching, and whatever. `SpecialBar` has a different column layout than `SpecialRow` and yet when I do this, the columns of `SpecialRow`s are now mimic the columns of `SpecialBar` and squish all the data to the right.

Any idea what may be happening?

```
class Table1 extends React.Component {
    <Table>
        <tbody>
            <SpecialBar {...this.props}/>
            {this.props.moreRows.map((row) => 
                <SpecialRow {...this.props} />
            )}
         </tbody>
    </Table>
}

class SpecialBar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td className='col-md-1'>Text A</td>
                <td className='col-md-10>Text B</td>
                <td className='col-md-1>Text C</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}

class SpecialRow extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <td className='col-md-2'>Stuff</td>
            <td className='col-md-2'>Stuff</td>
            <td className='col-md-2'>Stuff</td>
            <td className='col-md-2'>Stuff</td>
            <td className='col-md-1'>Stuff</td>
            <td className='col-md-1'>Stuff</td>
            <td className='col-md-1'>Stuff</td>
            <td className='col-md-1'>Stuff</td>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for this so that we can see what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea what may be happening?

What's happening is that the width of the second cell of the first row (`col-md-10`) is setting the width for all second cells in the following rows. That's how tables work.

You can work around it by giving that `col-md-10` cell a `colspan="10"`. Do the same for cells that have `col-md-2`, give them `colspan="2"`.

Comment: This helped me tremendously! Thank you!  As a follow-up question: when would you be using `colSpan` and when wouldn't you?

Comment: `colspan` is used when you want one table cell to extend to the next cells, that's about it. :) Only works for `td` elements, so there is no use for it outside a table. In your case, bootstrap only helps you to set the width of the cells.